# How to get back a deleted answer of mine?

Tags: discussion, answers

If an answer of mine was deleted, Who has the privilege to undelete it?

and if my answer was deleted by any other, not me, How much reputation of mine will be reduced?

Comment: let's get specific: deleted by whom?

Comment: deleted by any other, not me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have deleted your own answer and you know which question it is, then you can just go that question and you should be able to see your answer in light-pink color and you have an option to undelete the same too.

Users with more than 10k rep or moderators can see the deleted answers too.

Answer (score 13):

[image: I]
[image: hate]
[image: you]

### ಠ_ಠ

Comment: does rlly roy want to undelete that kind of answer? xD

Answer (score 1):

You, mods,and I think truted users have the privillage to undelete the post.
It does not matter who deleted it but you can always undelete it.

Comment: I think a poster can not undelete own post if it was deleted through spam/offensive flags, but that is a bit of a special case.

Comment: @Piskvor this is correct - if the post is "locked" then only diamond mods can undelete. *As far as I know* a post only becomes locked on spam/offensive auto-deletion, migration away to another site of if a moderator locks it.